# Plone: Recover password by email instead of username

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Is there a simple way to set recovering account's password to work with email instead of user name?

Or I must override `mail_password_form` template and it's related script?

(Our users seems to forget user ids, too...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Plone already has this case implemented in [`mail_password_form.pt`](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/82166581732a789a21a9e7b6319bf500b2050f66/Products/CMFPlone/browser/templates/mail_password_form.pt#L42).

```
            <label i18n:translate="label_my_user_name_is"
                   tal:condition="not:use_email_as_login"
                   for="userid">
                My user name is
            </label>
            <label i18n:translate="label_my_email_address_is"
                   tal:condition="use_email_as_login"
                   for="userid">
              My email address is
            </label>
```

In Site setup -> Security (`@@security-controlpanel`) check: `Use email address as login name` (Allows new users to login with their email address instead of specifying a separate login name. Existing users can still login with their user id until you use the @@migrate-to-emaillogin page as a site admin. It is recommended to do that immediately after changing this option.)

(Working for simple accounts, but not useful in my case - ldap accounts.)